# About Abi Encoder V2

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic

I came across the following code and found the term "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2". Can anybody be specific in telling what this actually means?

```
//pragma solidity ^0.5.2;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract test {

struct document{
   string ipfsHash;
   string documentName;
   bytes32 accessKey;
}

struct grantAccess{
   address owner;
   address single;     
}
```

This is a part of the code I found over the web.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solidity v0.4-v0.7

> The standard ABI coder does not allow arrays of dynamic types, structs
> or nested variables between the Solidity contract and the dApp.
>
> The ABI v2 coder; which allows structs, nested and dynamic variables
> to be passed into functions, returned from functions and emitted by
> events.
>
> **Note**: **Do not use experimental features on live deployments.**

### Solidity v0.8 and above

As per the list of [v0.8 breaking changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html), the ABIEncoderV2 is not experimental anymore - it is actually enabled by default by the compiler.

Comment: Wow. Solidity v0.8.0 has JUST BEEN RELEASED WITH ABI coder v2 activated by default!!!

Answer (score 9):

From the [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html) documentation:

> ABI coder v2 is activated by default.

So it is not experimental anymore, but a standard feature since Solidity v0.8.0.