# Get array of structs by giving address as parameter

Tags: solidity, remix

Here's my code:

```
contract company {

    struct contractDetails {
        string contractId;
        string companyA;
        string companyB;
        address A;
        address B;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string signHash;
        bool isSigned;
    }

    mapping (address => contractDetails) contractAddr;
    uint public counter = 0;

     function createContract(string memory _contractId, string memory _companyA, string memory _companyB, address _B) public {
        counter++;
        contractAddr[_B] = contractDetails(_contractId, _companyA, _companyB, msg.sender, _B, now, '', false);
    }

function getAllContracts(address _address) public view returns(contractDetails[] memory) {
        contractDetails[] memory y = new contractDetails[];
        for(uint i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            y[i] = contractAddrArr[i];
        }
        return(y);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the result as below:

```
address1 => [struct1, struct2, struct3......]
```

A function should return an array of structs by passing a user's address as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is impossible to return struct in solidity. Though you can use experimental ABIEncoderV2.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.9;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
contract company {

struct contractDetails {
    string contractId;
    string companyA;
    string companyB;
    address A;
    address B;
    uint256 timestamp;
    string signHash;
    bool isSigned;
}

mapping (address => contractDetails) contractAddr;
uint public counter = 0;

function createContract(string memory _contractId, string memory _companyA, string memory _companyB, address _B) public {
    counter++;
    contractAddr[_B] = contractDetails(_contractId, _companyA, _companyB, msg.sender, _B, now, '', false);
}

function getAllContracts(address _address) public view returns(contractDetails[] memory) {
    contractDetails[] memory y;
    for(uint i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        y[i] = contractAddr[_address];
    }
    return(y);
}
}
```

But, in live production, experimental feature should not be used.
[Link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64562/about-abi-encoder-v2)