# Is it possible to return a table of values in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, arrays

I am writing a code to return multiple values from two arrays simultaneously. I understand since I mentioned only one uint and one address as arguments in `returns`, the for loop is throwing an error. What can I do to be able to return multiple values from both the arrays? Following is my code snippet:

```
function listBest() public view returns(uint, address){
    for(uint p = 0; p < number; p++) {
        return(listScores, listScoredPeople[p]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure but it might be possible with Solidity ABI v2 encoding: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/64566/620

Comment: I AM using ABIencoderV2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* return multiple values, as per [Destructuring Assignments and Returning Multiple Values](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.1/control-structures.html?highlight=tuples#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values).

But your current code is going to return on the first iteration of the loop.

You could either:

- Create and return two arrays
- Define a struct that contains one member of each array, then return an array of the structs.